# rails variables between controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, activerecord, parameters

Y.A.N (yet another newbie)

Using rails, I have a 'students' controller and a 'contacts' controller and of course, a student model and contact model. contact belongs_to student and student has_many contacts. I have an index page of students that lists each student with the option to click "Add Contact" for each student.  I'm losing it when I try to call the contacts' 'new' action and subsequently the "new" view for contacts. How/where do i initialize the student and/or contact so the contact knows the student_id.  Right now, I'm passing the student to the new_contact_path but then I have to refer to the student_Id as params(:format) inside the contact controller in order to get it to work. this is obviously not the best way.
Any ideas  Pieces of code below:

```
ContactsController:
def new
    @contact = Contact.new
    @student = Student.find(params[:format])
end

students index:
<% @students.each do |student| %>
  <tr>          
    <td><%= link_to 'Contacts', new_contact_path(student) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can use nested resources. In this case you have student_id in contacts controller automatically (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to find the student with

```
@student = Student.find(params[:format])
```

there is definitely something wrong with your routes.

Your routes should be something like:

```
resources :students do
  resources :contacts
end
```

And your code should be:

```
@student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
```

The index view you posted should work fine provided you initialised @students properly.

Answer (score 1):

you could pass student_id in the new_contact_path link.

```
<%= link_to 'Contacts', new_contact_path(student, :student_id => student.id) %>
```

and in the controller

```
class ContactsController
  def new
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
  end
end
```